How to get the hot and selected style color for a listview?
Below is a TListView in vsIcon mode with Styles enabled on the project.

I want to be able to obtain that blue/greenish highlight color (style color), how do I do that?
I've been looking into Style Colors and Element Colors but couldn't quite understand it.
Thanks.

You did not say which style you used for your example, but by the looks of it, maybe Carbon.vsf. So, the following is based on that assumption.
When you open the Bitmap Style Designer and load the Carbon.vsf style, there is no ListView object listed  under Objects, but there is a ListBox object. I presume, but didn't confirm from the source code, that a ListView uses the style data of a ListBox.
The color of the focused item can be found in the style designer, in the object tree to the left, near the end, in item colors, listed as FocusEffect. If you select that FocusEffect and hit the Pick... button, A small window will pop up, showing that the color is $00725A26.
